# Add padding to text input when we use adjust pan in Android React Native?

Tags: react-native

[image]

i need to add padding in between last Text Input and Keyboard.
I have added `widnowsSoftInputMode:'adjustpan'` in manifest file and have tried using keyboard-avoiding-view but i didn't work?

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I've never thought about it but I guess you can do somethings with onFocus prop. You can use animations with onFocus then you can put it anywhere you want.